# How to plot multiple outputs separately to create a list of graphics?

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, output

I have a function which returns me multiple outputs like so:

```
{{0,0}}
{{0,0},{1,1}}
{{0.,0.},{0.5,0.707107},{1.,0.}}
{{0.,0.},{0.25,0.5},{0.5,0.},{0.75,0.5}}
{{0.,0.},{0.25,0.5},{0.5,0.},{0.75,0.5},{1.,1.}}
{{0.,0.},{0.125,0.353553},{0.25,0.},{0.375,0.353553},{0.5,0.707107},{0.625,1.06066}}
{{0.,0.},{0.125,0.353553},{0.25,0.},{0.375,0.353553},{0.5,0.707107},{0.625,1.06066},{0.75,0.707107}}
```

... and so on.
Note that each row is a separate output. Is there any way to plot each row with Graphics and then make a graphics list so that then I can use ListAnimate?

Comment: What do you mean, Plot {{0,0}}?  Place a point?

Comment: see `Map` https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html

Comment: I guess you are `Print-ing`, can you just `Sow/Reap` them. And then, having alist of outputs do whatever you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
mypoints = {
   {{0, 0}},
   {{0, 0}, {1, 1}},
   {{0., 0.}, {0.5, 0.707107}, {1., 0.}},
   {{0., 0.}, {0.25, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.}, {0.75, 0.5}},
   {{0., 0.}, {0.25, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.}, {0.75, 0.5}, {1., 1.}},
   {{0., 0.}, {0.125, 0.353553}, {0.25, 0.}, {0.375, 0.353553}, {0.5, 
     0.707107}, {0.625, 1.06066}},
   {{0., 0.}, {0.125, 0.353553}, {0.25, 0.}, {0.375, 0.353553}, {0.5, 
     0.707107}, {0.625, 1.06066}, {0.75, 0.707107}}};

GraphicsColumn[
 Graphics[{Hue[RandomReal[]], Point[#]}, Axes -> True, 
    ImageSize -> 100] & /@ mypoints ]
```

Comment: why not   ListAnimate[Graphics[{Hue[RandomReal[]], Point[#]}] & /@ mypoints]   ?

Comment: I would prefer this one       ListAnimate[Graphics[{PointSize[.2], Point[#]}] & /@ mypoints]

Comment: The poser asked that "...each row is a separate output."

Comment: I think that he noted that "each row is a separate output" and he is right because the outputs are not joined with comas.but I believe he wants to animate the rows.Your code is doing a good job in "plot each row with Graphics and then make a graphics list so that then I can use ListAnimate". What is OP's opinion???